# Passing data from one page to another page using POST ASP

Tags: html, post, asp-classic

I want to pass the data from page to another using POST and display first name & last name on my second page. But instead of names it does display the actual code. PLease see the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<FORM action="RetrieveData_Post.asp" id=form1 method=post name=form1>
First Name:
<br>
<INPUT id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" >
<br>
Last Name:
<br>
<INPUT id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" >
<br>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the first page and the second page is:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%
Response.Write("First Name: " & Request.Form("txtFirstName") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Last Name: " & Request.Form("txtLastName") & "<br>")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your web server support classic asp? Is it installed on your web server?

Answer (score 0):

Create an html page Gatherdata_post.htm

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<FORM action="RetrieveData_Post.asp" id=form1 method=post name=form1>
    First Name:
    <br>
    <INPUT id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" >
    <br>
    Last Name:
    <br>
    <INPUT id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" >
    <br>
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Save the page

Create an page Retrievedata_post.asp

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%
Response.Write("First Name: " & Request.Form("txtFirstName") & "<br>")
Response.Write("Last Name: " & Request.Form("txtLastName") & "<br>")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Run Gatherdata_post.htm by right-clicking the page and selecting View in browser.
In this way you can pass values

Answer (score 0):

First, this assumes that you are running this on a server running IIS and not just double-clicking the HTML file. You need a server to process the actual code, and IIS is the most common server that will process Classic ASP.

Second, you need to make sure that ASP is enabled. Classic ASP is not enabled by default on IIS6+ ([Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737992%28v=WS.10%29.aspx))

1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, and then click Web Service Extensions.
2. In the details pane, click Active Server Pages, and then click Allow.

It may be a little different depending on the version of IIS you are running.

Answer (score -1):

**Source Page**

The Source Page has an HTML Button with a jQuery Click event handler. When the Button is clicked, an HTML Form is created and appended to the BODY Tag of the page. The action is set to the Destination page (Page2.aspx). Using the AddParameter function values of the Name TextBox and the Technology DropDownList is appended to the Form as Hidden Fields and then the Form is submitted

```
<input type="button" id="btnPost" value="Send" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnPost").bind("click", function () {
            //Create a Form
            var $form = $("<form/>").attr("id", "data_form")
                            .attr("action", "Page2.aspx")
                            .attr("method", "post");
            $("body").append($form);

            //Append the values to be send
            AddParameter($form, "name", $("#txtName").val());
            AddParameter($form, "technology", $("#ddlTechnolgy").val());

            //Send the Form
            $form[0].submit();
        });
    });
    function AddParameter(form, name, value) {
        var $input = $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden")
                                .attr("name", name)
                                .attr("value", value);
        form.append($input);
    }
</script>
```

**Destination Page**

On the Destination page (Page2.aspx), in the Page Load event of the ASP.Net Page the values of the two posted fields are fetched and are printed on the page. The below code has been done in C# but similar can be done for other technologies.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["name"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["technology"]))
        {
            Response.Write("<u>Values using Form Post</u><br /><br />");
            Response.Write("<b>Name:</b> " + Request.Form["name"] + " <b>Technology:</b> " + Request.Form["technology"]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Pros:**
 Best in class as there is 100% guarantee of data being send that too in hidden form.
Pros: Best in class as there is 100% guarantee of data being send that too in hidden form.

**Cons:** 
Requires Server side technology for fetching posted data.Requires Server side technology for fetching posted data.

Comment: This is not Classic ASP.